# How can I search directories starting with a certain letter?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

How can I search through directories starting with a certain letter with the Linux find command.

For example I want to search all directories starting with the letter `a` for a file or directory starting with `b`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try a find in a find:

```
find . -type d -name "a*" -exec find {} -name "b" \;
```

Starting at the current directory (`.`), find will look for all directories starting with the letter a recursively. For each directory it finds, it will look inside it for a file named b.

If you only want it to look in the folders starting with **a**, and no directories in those **a*** folders, use maxdepth:

```
find . -type d -name "a*" -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 -name "b" \;
```

to get rid of errors:

```
find . -type d -name "a*" 2> /dev/null -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 -name "b" \;
```

Comment: nix the `-type f` on the interior `find` -- OP's question indicates "b" could be file or directory.

Comment: Yeah I had that part in mind so I just did a file example. If I take off the type it will also show symbolic links among other things he doesn't want -- if there happens to be one named "b".

Comment: well, he doesn't specify *not* wanting symlinks, so i'd make the opposite assumption -- but we've pointed out the limitations now, so he can make up his own mind.  :)

Comment: True enough, that way my command wont wrap either.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update for people who might end up on this question.

In addition to the solution [**John T**](https://superuser.com/users/1931/john-t) provided, I have also found that you can exclude directories by using the prune switch (should have read the man pages sooner I guess, hehe.)

So for example if I want to search all directories for file or directory "b" except directories starting with an "a" I can do this

```
find . -path 'a*' -prune -o -name "b" -print
```

bing

Answer (score 1):

you can also use find -regex...

```
find -regex .*/a.*/b
```